# Monitoring voltage state without interfering

Tags: arduino, signal

I have a CO2 laser cutter, and I am designing as circuit to turn on some outlets whenever the laser is firing.

The laser is turned on by a 5V logic connection to the high voltage power supply. If I can intercept this signal, I can tell when the laser is on.

But how can I check whether or not that line is HIGH or LOW using an Arduino without interfering with the circuit on the laser cutter? I thought of two ways, but I have a problem with both.

1) Simply connect the signal wire to one of my Arduino's digital I/O pins. Problem: the Arduino is operated on a PSU seperate from the laser cutter, so the ground pins would not be the same.

2) Use an optoisolator that reads when the line is high. Pros: the Arduino and the laser cutter don't have to have the same ground. Cons: I would have to run the signal line throught a 1k ohm resistor and into the optoisolator. This would add resistance to the signal line AND prevent bidirectional signals.

So, in conclusion, how does one check the voltage state of a signal line without interfering with the signal line?

Comment: If you want the Arduino to be isolated, and do not want to source from the logic 5V signal at all, you will have to use some external or the high-voltage power supply to power the laser-side circuitry.

Comment: What is the source of these 5V? How much current can it drive? What is the output resistance?

Comment: The thing is that I don't know. I assume its a 5V logic level signal coming from the lasers controller board, so it should be able to handle 1kohm and an an optoisolator, but I thought there would be a solution for this sort of problem. Reading voltage without adding a whole kohm of resistance to the signal line.

Comment: Any solution like this will require some power supply on both sides. Do you have the controller board specs?

Comment: Why would adding the 1k+opto to your 5v signal line be a problem? The signal from your controller device to the HV psu shouldn't run through the 1k and I would expect the controller should be able to source a few extra mA on that line ...

Comment: You don't want to put the opto LED + resistor in series - it would go in parallel with the input, but you need to be very careful you don't load the output (perhaps it goes high-Z at startup) in such a way as to cause the CO2 laser to start inadvertently under some conditions (load it in the direction of turning it off). Both the kV voltage and many watts of light output are worthy of healthy respect- even my bitty 40W one can do real damage.

Comment: Is the control signal pulled to ground if off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cons: I would have to run the signal line throught a 1k ohm resistor and into the optoisolator. This would add resistance to the signal line AND prevent bidirectional signals.

This is not correct. Tee off the 5 V control line and place the current limiting resistor in the tee, not in the main line.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq8GCo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 5 V control signal will have to be able to source enough current to drive the LED, or you will have to buffer it.

Comment: I think this is exactly what OP means..

Comment: Sorry, you've shown exactly what I needed, and I should have been able to figure that out for myself. I must have posted this question before my morning coffee kicked in. Thank you!